# How to show captcha error message using the Silverstripe honeypot module?

Tags: silverstripe

I am trying to implement the honeypot spam module here:
https://github.com/studiobonito/silverstripe-spamprotection-honeypot

It is showing up fine in the source code because it is a hidden field using this:

```
$Fields.dataFieldByName(Captcha).Field
```

However when there is a value added to the field it throws a validation error (which is correct). My problem is I can't get the message to appear on the front end. I am trying to use:

```
<span class="form-error">$Fields.dataFieldByName(Captcha).Message</span>
```

But no luck..

If I render the form like this

```
$ConactForm
```

The error messages shows when there is a value added. How do I show the error message using my way though?

--

```
<% with ContactForm %>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 contact-form">
        <% loop $Fields %>
            <p class="message form-error">$Message $fieldName $messageType</p>
        <% end_loop %>
        <form $FormAttributes class="clearfix">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                $Fields.dataFieldByName(Name).Field
                <span class="form-error">$Fields.dataFieldByName(Name).Message</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                $Fields.dataFieldByName(Email).Field
                <span class="form-error">$Fields.dataFieldByName(Email).Message</span>
            </div>

            $Fields.dataFieldByName(Captcha).Field
            <span class="form-error">$Fields.dataFieldByName(Captcha).Message</span>

            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <button class="form-control btn btn-send" name="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
<% end_with %>
```

Comment: Would a user ever be able to fill in the honey pot field? As the field is hidden this shouldn't happen, so we would never need to display the validation error.

Comment: Nope they won't be able to fill it out. But I was adding a value to the hidden field to test that the module was actually doing its job, which it is, but I can't get it to show the validation error message that it is generating. It redirects back with the data in the fields etc. I can only get it to display if rendering the form like `$ContactForm`.

Comment: Isn't the idea that it is meant for bots so it doesn't really matter whether you show the error or not?
Also you are saying that you can see the message when using the more descriptive way of rendering the form, or you can't? I'm a bit confused sorry...

Comment: also have you seen this? https://github.com/studiobonito/silverstripe-spamprotection-honeypot/issues/2

Comment: @BenDubuisson, yip so its meant for bots so it doesn't matter necessarily if we show the error or not BUT it should be showing the error message but its not so just one of the things that annoys me haha :) Nope I hadn't seen that.